# Varna of the Jatt people acc to Hindu scriptures?

Tags: caste-system, varna, varnashrama

It is said that Jatts are originally from central Asia and hence either pure Aryans or mixture of Aryan fathers and native Indian Rajanya women
Have they been mentioned in the scriptures?
Do they fall under the Varnashram?

Comment: (Not the downvoter) Jats are Kshatriya

Comment: Jats say they came from jata/hair locks of Lord Shiva.. Need to see scriptures if any such story is present.

Comment: @The Destroyer♦ the Jaats have the highest percentage of steppe ancestry in all of South Asia; hence there are research articles insisting that they are central Asian warrior tribes who settled in India